# Clip UIImage with valid content

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

There is an image that it's valid content is only the middle part, other is transparent area, how to get the valid part's rect and clip it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I autocrop a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061800/how-do-i-autocrop-a-uiimage)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.