# Incorrect saving of transparent UIImage to Photo Library as png with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: swift, iphone, uikit, transparency, save-image

I have a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48759198/19276981) `cropAlpha()` that trims the extra space defined by the transparency.

```
func cropAlpha() -> UIImage {
    let cgImage = self.cgImage!
    
    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerPixel:Int = 4
    let bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue

    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo),
          let ptr = context.data?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
    else { return self }

    context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
    
    var minX = width
    var minY = height
    var maxX: Int = 0
    var maxY: Int = 0
    
    for x in 1 ..< width {
        for y in 1 ..< height {
            let i = bytesPerRow * Int(y) + bytesPerPixel * Int(x)
            let a = CGFloat(ptr[i + 3]) / 255.0
            
            if a == 1 {
                if (x < minX) { minX = x }
                if (x > maxX) { maxX = x }
                if (y < minY) { minY = y }
                if (y > maxY) { maxY = y }
            }
        }
    }
    
    let rect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(minX),y: CGFloat(minY), width: CGFloat(maxX - minX), height: CGFloat(maxY-minY))
    
    let croppedImage = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!
    let ret = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImage)

    return ret
}
```

The image returned by this function has transparent elements and I put it in the ImageView: `presenterImageView.image = imagePNG`. It [works as it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEWGW.jpg). But when I try to save UIImage to Photo Gallery, transparent background turns [white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6cX2.jpg).

```
let image = maskedImage?.cropAlpha()
    
let imagePNGData = image!.pngData()
let imagePNG = UIImage(data: imagePNGData!)

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagePNG!, nil, nil, nil)
```

If I don't use that function, I get the result I [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBxFt.jpg), but the image has too much wasted space. I don't understand what could be the reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` does not handle properly saving a `UIImage` with premultiplied alpha (or at least the result of saving such image is not what you expect) and your cropping method uses premultipliedLast format. You also can't just simply change `CGImageAlphaInfo` to a non-premultiplied format because it is not supported there (you will see an error `CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination` if you try that). But what you can do is convert the cropped image to `CIImage`, unpremultiply alpha and convert back to `UIImage`. To do that your saving code could look like below (however I recommend removing force unwrapping from this code if you plan to use it in final app):

```
let image = maskedImage?.cropAlpha()

let ciImage = CIImage(image: image!)!.unpremultiplyingAlpha()
let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
    
let imagePNGData = uiImage.pngData()
let imagePNG = UIImage(data: imagePNGData!)

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imagePNG!, nil, nil, nil)
```